# Bootstrap 4 - lay 4 elements in a row and wrap to another row

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4. How can I automatically wrap divs so that after, let's say 4 elements (the elements are the same added by a CMS), it automatically wraps to the next row so it looks like:

```
_ _ _ _
_ _ _ _
_ _ _ _
_ ...
```

I have been looking at flex and the grid system included in Bootstrap 4 but having no luck.

Thank you

Comment: Use the 12-column grid system with `col-3` columns.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the answer. The wrapping div should have the following classes: d-flex and flex-wrap.